# Is there any function that learns from one dataset and matches with a new one?

Tags: r

Does anyone know how can I write code that will learn from a dataset and after that when someone imports a new dataset for example, to match if they have a same observation? To be more specific i want to match genes of drugs with genes of patients.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://stat545.com/join-cheatsheet.html

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example of your input and output. Thank you.

Comment: Phil thank you this is very close to what i am trying to achieve, but i would like to joining the two datasets from the observation of the one(patient data)  to the name of the column of the other dataset which will be the drug which has as observations the genes of the drug